# Yii2 - TypeaheadBasic calling data from table

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I am currently using Yii2 with typeahead basic. I am trying to fetch data from the mysql table, which is 'staff_name'

Currently I am following the guide, and here is my code( i put everything in the view first for testing(model is present but nothing is defined in there),

```
$data = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 
    'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
    'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
    'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];   

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin()?>
 <?=$form->field($model, 'staff_name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
]);?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

It works fine when I hardcoded like this. But I need help on how to fetch the staff_name column data inside the mysql table. I tried something like: `$data = [StaffMain::find()->all()];` but I get a 'null' in the textinput field as I type.

EDIT: Based on the scaisEdge answer, I had to change the query a bit.

```
$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT staff_name FROM staff_main')->queryColumn();
```

OR

```
$data = StaffMain::find()->select(['staff_name'])->asArray()->column();
```

Comment: Is not clear you want populate $data with data form a db table or you need retrive the $model->staff_name.. please explain better..

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry for the confusion, I want to populate the $data with data from a db table called StaffMain(a column called staff_name to be exact). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only populate the  $data with the resulf of StaffMain model column staff_name you should use

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin()?>
   <?=$form->field($model, 'staff_name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
      'data' => StaffMain::find()->select('staff_name')->asArray()column(),
       'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
      'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
  ]);?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

or

```
$data = StaffMain::find()->select('staff_name')->asArray()column();

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin()?>
   <?=$form->field($model, 'staff_name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
     'data' => $data,
     'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
     'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
]);?>
```

Comment: OKay now I can see the connection is made in the log, listing the staff_name column after it opens staff_main table. But the typeahead still did not output any names.  I tried without the model and still the same. Maybe I am missing one more line?

Comment: Try assign $data outside .. i have update the answer .. hope is useful

Comment: I did try putting it in the controllers, outside, etc but it still wont show up.

Somehow I tried using the Select2 widget(http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) and it works fine with your codes. I am not sure what was wrong though. I really want to use typeahead though if possible.

Comment: I got it working by changing the ->all() to ->column query. Thanks a lot for helping! Accepted answer!